# Update NULL date field to match another date field value

Tags: sql, sql-update, isnull

I am trying to update my NULL field of **DM_EVENT_T.date_ops_end** to match the date reflected in **MAX(DM_REPORT_JOURNAL.date_report)**:

```
SELECT DM_EVENT_T.event_id, 
       DM_EVENT_T.date_ops_end, 
       MAX(DM_REPORT_JOURNAL.date_report) AS [Final Report Date]
FROM   DM_EVENT_T INNER JOIN
       DM_REPORT_JOURNAL ON DM_EVENT_T.event_id = DM_REPORT_JOURNAL.event_id
WHERE  (DM_REPORT_JOURNAL.entity_type = 'Daily Operations') AND (DM_EVENT_T.date_ops_end IS NULL)
GROUP BY 
      DM_EVENT_T.date_ops_end, DM_EVENT_T.event_id
```

I am pretty new to SQL, so any insight as to the method or logic behind a solution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A [shorter example](http://sscce.org/) would help.
Did you want to return a different value when date_ops_end is null, or did you actually want to set date_ops_end to a value?

Comment: Hi Jeremy - I'm trying to actually set date_ops_end to same value as MAX(DM_REPORT_JOURNAL.date_report). I'll try and work up a shorter example as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum value can be stored in a temporary variable and can be set using UPDATE
If this is not the expected value, probably with some example data and desired output, this can be modified.

```
DECLARE @maxVal datetime

SELECT @maxVal = MAX(DM_REPORT_JOURNAL.date_report)
FROM   DM_EVENT_T INNER JOIN
       DM_REPORT_JOURNAL 
       ON DM_EVENT_T.event_id = DM_REPORT_JOURNAL.event_id
WHERE  (DM_REPORT_JOURNAL.entity_type = 'Daily Operations') AND (DM_EVENT_T.date_ops_end IS NULL)
GROUP BY 
      DM_EVENT_T.date_ops_end, DM_EVENT_T.event_id

UPDATE DM_EVENT_T
set date_ops_end= @maxVal
where date_ops_end IS NULL
```

Comment: I received the error: "Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query" for this part of the script: "SELECT @maxVal = MAX(DM_REPORT_JOURNAL.date_report)".......would I need to add something like this somewhere?: CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', 102)

Comment: change @maxVal type to datetime